# Simplify method with many for and Ifs statement

Tags: java

ExtractSourceQueryOB is an object that represents queries, a query could have a master query and in this case the master query should not be removed from the list,  querySet contains strings of keys that represent queries that are required in this operation but it doesnt take account of the possibility of that query having a master. So i tried to loop through all queries checking that query has a master and in that case add that object (ExtractSourceQueryOB ) to the final list.

```
private List<ExtractSourceQueryOB> checkRequiredQueries(List<ExtractSourceQueryOB> extractSourceQueryList, ExtractElement extractElement) {
            Set<ExtractSourceQueryOB> queryList =   new HashSet();
            Set<String> querySet = new HashSet();
            fillUsedSymbolList(querySet, extractElement);

            for(ExtractSourceQueryOB extractSourceQuery : extractSourceQueryList) {
                if(extractSourceQuery.getMaster() != null ) {
                    for(ExtractSourceQueryOB extractSourceQuery2 : extractSourceQueryList) {
                        if(extractSourceQuery.getMaster().equals(extractSourceQuery2.getSymbol())){
                            queryList.add(extractSourceQuery2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
             for (ExtractSourceQueryOB extractSourceQuery : extractSourceQueryList) {
                for (String s : querySet) {
                    if (extractSourceQuery.getSymbol().equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                        queryList.add(extractSourceQuery);
                    }
                }
            }
            return new ArrayList<>(queryList);
        }
```

How can i simplify this method ?

Comment: I think this kind of question is more suited in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

You could eliminate the second `for` by combining that code with the first. Like,

```
for(ExtractSourceQueryOB extractSourceQuery : extractSourceQueryList) {
    if(extractSourceQuery.getMaster() != null ) {
        for(ExtractSourceQueryOB extractSourceQuery2 : extractSourceQueryList) {
            if(extractSourceQuery.getMaster().equals(extractSourceQuery2.getSymbol())){
                queryList.add(extractSourceQuery2);
            }
        }
    }
    for (String s : querySet) {
        if (extractSourceQuery.getSymbol().equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
            queryList.add(extractSourceQuery);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private List<ExtractSourceQueryOB> checkRequiredQueries(List<ExtractSourceQueryOB> extractSourceQueryList, ExtractElement extractElement) {
        Set<ExtractSourceQueryOB> queryList = new HashSet();
        Set<String> querySet = new HashSet();
        fillUsedSymbolList(querySet, extractElement);

        for (ExtractSourceQueryOB extractSourceQuery : extractSourceQueryList) {
            if (isyUsedAsMaster(extractSourceQuery,extractSourceQueryList) || isUsed(extractSourceQuery,querySet, extractSourceQueryList)) {
                queryList.add(extractSourceQuery);
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(queryList);
    }



  private boolean isyUsedAsMaster(ExtractSourceQueryOB extractSourceQuery, List<ExtractSourceQueryOB> extractSourceQueryList) {
            if (extractSourceQuery.getMaster() != null) {
                for (ExtractSourceQueryOB extractSourceQuery2 : extractSourceQueryList) {
                    if (extractSourceQuery.getMaster().equals(extractSourceQuery2.getSymbol())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


    private boolean isUsed(ExtractSourceQueryOB extractSourceQuery,  Set<String> querySet, List<ExtractSourceQueryOB> extractSourceQueryList) {
        for (String s : querySet) {
            if(extractSourceQuery.getSymbol().equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Previous answer above is correct but this is with some refactoring